# Ionic/Angular custom page transition

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic app that has a "preloader" immediately before the app starts.  Ideally I'd like the main page after the pre-loader to appear immediately, instead of slide-in.  Is there a way to programmatically define what transition to use on a one-off basis?  Normally the sliding is fine, but just not for the transition from the pre-loader to the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Defining in controller $ionicViewSwitcher and $state

now in ng-click inside a or button tags call:

```
//here transition name
$ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection('forward');
//here next state name
$state.go("main.map");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE').config(function($ionicConfigProvider){
    $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');
});
```

Hope this helps you.